# Как сделать рандомайзер целых чисел в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, int

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как сделать рандомайзер целых чисел в JS?

Comment: "рандомайзер целых чисел" - ??

Comment: `parseInt(Math.random()*100); //0-99 `

Answer (score 2):

```js
function randomInt(l, u) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(l)) { l = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER }
  if (!Number.isInteger(u) || u < l) { u = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (++u - l)) + l
}


console.log(randomInt())
console.log(randomInt(1, 100))
```